# Different conditional behaviour between standard and tenary operators when working with nulls

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two almost identically looking conditionals, but they behave in different way and I can't explain why. Can any one tell me why is that happening?

```java
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    Long aggValue = null;
    Long nextValue = null;

    System.out.println(process1(aggValue, nextValue));
    System.out.println(process2(aggValue, nextValue));
}

public Long process1(Long aggValue, Long nextValue) {
    if (aggValue == null) {
        return nextValue;
    } else {
        if (nextValue == null) {
            return aggValue;
        }
    }
    return aggValue + nextValue;
}

public Long process2(Long aggValue, Long nextValue) {
    return aggValue == null ? nextValue : nextValue == null ? aggValue : aggValue + nextValue;
}
```

Result:

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I expected both methods to just return null, but the second one returns NPE. Debugger on process2 method is expecting this and already showing NPE near nextValue (true part of first conditional).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use compound logical expressions `(using && or ||)` you need one more apparently redundant ternary operator to finish the expression. That would be the last one, checking for `nextValue != null` when you already know it isn't null. This permits returning a valid `sum` or `null if both are null`

```
public Long process2(Long aggValue, Long nextValue) {
    return (aggValue == null) ? nextValue
            : nextValue == null ? aggValue
                    : nextValue != null ? aggValue + nextValue : null;
}
```

But I would stick with the first method with minor changes. Since you are doing explicit returns just get rid of the `else if` and keep the return statements. The following seems rather straightforward to me.

```
public Long process1(Long aggValue, Long nextValue) {
    if (aggValue == null) {
         return nextValue; // returns nextValue or null
    }
    if (nextValue == null) {
         return aggValue; // returns aggValue or null
    }
    // At this point, neither value is null
     return aggValue + nextValue; // return the sum.
 }
```